# awk: print 0 instead of blank when no lines were processed

Tags: shell, awk

Consider this awk example that sums up all values of a particular field in a file:

```
awk '{sum+=$2} END{print "total: ",sum}' file.txt
```

When the file is empty awk won't output anything for sum. Is it possible to output '0' in those cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of my preference (most to least preferred) for this specific use-case:

```
awk '{sum+=$2} END{print "total: ",sum+0}' file.txt
```

or

```
awk '{sum+=$2} END{printf "total: %d\n",sum}' file.txt
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$2} END{print "total: ",sum}' file.txt
```